# Make terminal cursor blink

Tags: shell, csh, tcsh

I can't find the option in `man` page to adjust cursor settings like: shape, blink, blink rate, color, etc.

I know how to edit the `.cshrc` file to customize the prompt like adding/removing username, machine, current working directory, etc. But I can't find options for cursor.

Any suggestions on how to do so for C-shell specifically?

Comment: It's up to your terminal emulator to decide how the cursor should behave, not the shell. You can check [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92743/198262) how to influence a few things using ANSI escape sequences _if the terminal supports and honors them_. This is not specific to C shell, you could do it in any program.

Comment: @CherryDT I tried using the code attached in the answer as my `.cshrc` file. When I open terminal, I get many lines like the following: `-en ]P0000000` `cursor_style_default=0: Command not found.`
My terminal is `xterm`. When I check the version in `Help -> About` I see that I have `GNOME Terminal 2.31.3`

Comment: From i.e. [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/gnome/gnome-terminal), I conclude that the Gnome terminal understands VT102, VT220, and xterm. If you want to issue the bare escape sequences by yourself, look up the documentation for the [xterm control sequences](http://www.xfree86.org/4.5.0/ctlseqs.html). Alterntaively, you could use `tput` to generate them. There should be a man-page for _tput_ on your system.

Comment: @user1934428 AFAICT there is no terminfo capability for blinking cursor, though `cvvis` may do it for you

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the code for blinking cursor , but you can try placing this code in your `.bashrc` file or `.zshrc` file:

```
# For changing cursor
#echo '\e[5 q'    #  This a thin line

echo '\e[4 q'     # this is underscore
```

Note this doesn't blink the cursor , it only change the cursor to underscore or thin line cursor

Comment: Acually, `4` is a `|` cursor, add one to get flashing. So `\e[5 q` should give you a flashing bar, and `\e[1 q` a flashing block cursor. This all supposes your teminal properly supports this. I note that _Windows Terminal_ does support blinking cursors.

Answer (score 0):

To see the settings :
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-blink-time

```
user@lenovo:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-blink-time
1200
```

to set a different value (in this case 200ms):

```
user@lenovo:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-blink-time 200
```